# How to set focus on TextBox in Silverlight 4 out-of-browser popup

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser

I have a simple [`ChildWindow`](http://tothsolutions.com/Blog/post/Silverlight-3-ChildWindow-Modal-Popup.aspx) popup in Silverlight 4 (beta).

**Important:** This is an **out-of-browser** application.

i want to auto set focus on a `TextBox` control when the window opens.

I've tried a couple things :

The following code doesn't seem to do anything. I don't think the control is ready to be focussed after 'Loading'.

```
    private void ChildWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

This works, but its klunky.

```
    private void ChildWindow_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          if (_firstTime == true) {
              textBox1.Focus();
             _firstTime = false;
          }
    }
```

Isn't there a better way? I always had to do horrible things like this in WinForms but was hoping not to have to anymore.

Note: This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124649/how-do-i-give-a-textbox-focus-in-silverlight) is for in browser only. It suggests calling `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();` which doesn't work and in fact gives an error when running on Silverlight 4 beta out-of-browser.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem in SilverLight 4 (OOB) and I noticed that the tab sequence would set focus to a control that i could not see.  What appears to be happening is the focus is being set to your control (first one in the tab sequence) and then for some reason the focus moves to the ContentControl (name ="content"), which (i think) is the parent of the child window.

ContentControl by default has IsTabStop=true.
see....
[Why would I want IsTabStop set to true on a ContentControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522477/why-would-i-want-istabstop-set-to-true-on-a-contentcontrol)
To set the ContentControl.IsTabStop = false for all ContentControls in your app, add this to your styles.xaml.

```
   <Style  TargetType="ContentControl" >
         <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    </Style>
```

The same issue happens with the tab sequence on the MainPage.  This style will also fix this.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. This did the trick for me (Silverlight 4 application).

Comment: This was the trick that did it for my ChildWindow also.  All the other 'tricks' didn't work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.  You need to handle for two test cases:
1.  Setting the focus in the browser.
2.  Setting the focus out of the browser.

Your code you that you showed in the Loaded event will work perfectly fine out of the browser.  All that is necessary is to refactor it to handle both cases:

```
private void ChildWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (App.current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
}
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: i haven't tried this again yet, but the problem was it didnt work for the Loaded event for out of browser. remember this is a child window - not just a 'regular control'

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the posts but after doing a little research the below thing work for me

in Xamal:

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" Height="25" Width="200" Margin="38,50,0,0" Name="txtUserName" Text="{Binding LoginInfo.UserName,Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="1" ></TextBox>

// Initialiazing Main Part View Model
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mainPartViewModel"></param>
public ChildWindowLoginControl(MainPartViewModel mainPartViewModel)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = mainPartViewModel;
     System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();
     this.GotFocus += (s, e) => { txtUserName.Focus(); };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to use your `GotFocus` way for Silverlight 3 application written in IronPython when I wanted to set focus in `ChildWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
protected override void OnOpened()
{
    base.OnOpened();
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the post, but i have find the work done through following.

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (App.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
        {
            txtSalesOrderNo.Focus(); 
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();
            txtSalesOrderNo.Focus(); 
        }

    }
```