# Why would I want IsTabStop set to true on a ContentControl?

Tags: silverlight, focus, contentcontrol

Given the following:

- setting IsTabStop to false on a ContentControl will not prevent its content from acting as a tab-stop
- setting IsTabStop to true will result in an invisible tab-stop, which does nothing, in your application

I have the following two questions:

1. Why is IsTabStop true by default for the ContentControl
2. Why would I ever want the ControlControl to act as a tab-stop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Douglas is correct `ContentControl` simply inherits the default value of `IsTabStop` from `Control`.  Also there is no good reason to assume that the value of `true` is less valid for a `ContentControl` than it is for `Control`.

For example, you might have a control that expects its content be something graphical such a set of `Shape` elements or an `Image`.  However your control may perform certain operations on the content when the user presses specific keys.

Answer (score 2):

The ContentControl gets it's IsTabStop property from Control, so all controls can be tab stops, including ContentControls.

I'm not sure why it is true by default for a ContentControl though, probably just because it defaults to true in Control.

Comment: This mirrors my own thoughts for in respect of question 1.  I guess the answer to question 2 might just be that the ability to set the ContentControl as a tabstop is a side effect of it inheriting from Control.