# Setting the focus on login childwindow in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

When my silverlight application has loaded a silverlight childwindow pops up and require the user to login. I want to set the focus on the username field in the childwindow. This isn't working. I've tried with the classic

```
loaded += event...
```

I read another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126424/setting-initial-control-focus-in-silverlight)  the problem with that was that now silverlight control is hosted like a object, and not in `<asp:silverlight>` so I had problem getting that javascript working. I tried putting an id on the object in silverlight .asp page but didn't work. 
Does anybody have any ideas of how to set focus on the childwindow in SL 4 ?

Comment: What does the "classic" loaded event look like?  It would help if you showed us the actual code you have tried.

Comment: I have a childwindow called Loginwindow that is that last to load. And in that child class I've hooked up the Loaded +=new RoutedEventHandler(LoginWindow_Loaded); and then in that method added the loginName.focus();  It seems like the problem is that the browser isn't focusing on the actual silverlight control. Because as soon as I click anywhere in the silverlight window, I get the right focus.

Comment: Try editing your question to include the code, comments are not a good place for additional details.  Also show the attempt to focus the silverlight object element in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with a little bit of help from the link I posted in [the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126424/setting-initial-control-focus-in-silverlight)
The problem was that my silverlight application didn't get the focus when it was loaded. So by adding the javascript the problem got solved:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {

        document.getElementById('silverObj').focus();
    }
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" id="silverObj" width="100%" height="100%">
```

This way I was able to get the focus on the silverlight control, and then I just hooked up the loaded event on my childwindow to focus my username.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in constructor:

System.Windows.Browser.**HtmlPage.Plugin.Focus();**

Hope it helps!